# Cannot install signed release build of APK (Got INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries)

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I had an app made in ionc in Google play store. Which is very old. And now I have built app from scratch using flutter with same `package id` as before.

**Problem**,

My new app update is accepted by play store and is available for download. The app gets downloaded, but says `Can't install MyApp`

I then tried the following

1. Installed release build of `apk` => Installation successful
2. I signed the release build with `.keystore` file => Installation failed

What I tried is

1. Clear play store cache
2. And tried signing app in following ways

`Using APKSIGNER`

```
Step 1 zipalign -v 4 app-release.apk MyApp.apk
Step 2 apksigner sign --ks myapp.keystore --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true MyApp.apk
```

`Using Jar Signer`

```
Step 1: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myapp.keystore app-release.apk myappalias
Step 2: zipalign -v 4 app-release.apk MyApp.apk
```

I tried installing other app both signed and unsigned release build, both worked.

**UPDATE**
tried to install via adb

```
adb install MyApp.apk
```

Got following error

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
```

Can anybody shed light on this, what is wrong in the case of this particular App?

Comment: You can't install an unsigned app. So it must have been signed with some other key. Maybe the default debug key.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann the problem is i am trying to install manually signed release build of apk. Which doesn't work. But other app with different bundle id work if i sign its release build with its keystore file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who stumble upon this thread. Here is how I fixed

The issue was due to `zipalign`

Add marked line to main `application` tag

```
<application
         android:extractNativeLibs="true"  // <--- Add this line
```

If you don't want to add above line in manifest file you can add `-p` tag while executing `zipalign`

```
zipalign -p 4 app.apk app-aligned.apk
```